# Indexing exported elements from inxex.ts by string

Tags: typescript

I have a folder named **nodes** in my project. Inside there are some classes but important is **index.tsx** file which is exporting it. The index.tsx looks:

```
export * from './processStep/ProcessStepNodeFactory';
export * from './processStep/ProcessStepNodeModel';
export * from './processStep/ProcessStepNodeWidget';
```

Now I would like to import everything from it:

```
import * as nodes from './nodes';
```

And now if I am trying to index **nodes** using string:

```
const foo = nodes['ProcessStepNodeFactory']
```

I am getting typescript error:

> TrayItemWidget.tsx TypeScript error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to
>   index type 'typeof
>   import("PATHTO/nodes/index")'.
>   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type
>   'typeof
>   import("PATHTO/nodes/index")'.
>   TS7053

Of course, I can access **"nodes.ProcessStepNodeFactory"** but I want to change string index programmatically using some prefixes on so. Could someone help please how to avoid this typescript error? Thank you

Comment: It seems that the error you posted is incomplete. typeof what?

Comment: I edited question

Comment: Why do you use `nodes['ProcessStepNodeFactory']` instead of `nodes.ProcessStepNodeFactory`?

Comment: because I want to have library of nodes and then index them by variable like:
`nodes[`${nodeType}NodeModel`]`

Comment: TypeScript doesn't like this, because it can't infer the type of the value you accessed. You might want to first cast `nodes` to `any` or `{ [key:string]:T }` where `T` is the expected type no matter what key you use.

Comment: Not sure how to implement it have this code snippet whwich causing error
`let node = new nodes[\`${nodeType}NodeModel\`](name, model.type === "in" ? "rgb(192,255,0)" : "rgb(0,192,255)");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came across this question after experiencing it myself. You could fall back to `const` so it can type-casted.

So, instead of:

```js
import * as nodes from './nodes';
```

You could do it like:

```js
const nodes: { [key: string]: any } = require('./nodes');
```

*It looks ugly, I know.*